# Optimize TSQL when joining a table created using a Table-Valued Function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

The following code runs in less than a second:

```
WITH GRIBS AS
(
    SELECT TOP 720 
        gfm.[ID],
        gfm.[FileName],
        gfm.[UTCDate] AS [TimeStep]
    FROM [hrdps].[GRIBFileMetrics]() gfm
    WHERE gfm.[Field] = 'WEARN_SFC_0'
    ORDER BY gfm.[UTCDate] DESC
)
SELECT
    b.[POIID],
    grib.[TimeStep],
    AVG(ISNULL(brain.[Amount], 0.0)) AS [Rainfall],
    grib.[FileName] 
FROM [storm].[BasinRain] brain
    LEFT JOIN [storm].[BasinGCSMap] bmap ON brain.[BasinGCSMapID] = bmap.[ID]
    LEFT JOIN [storm].[Basin] b ON b.[ID] = bmap.[BasinID]
    LEFT JOIN [storm].[POI] poi ON poi.[ID] = b.[POIID]
    FULL OUTER JOIN GRIBS grib ON brain.[TimeStep] = grib.[TimeStep]
GROUP BY b.[POIID], grib.[TimeStep], grib.[FileName]
```

Creating the GRIBS table involves parsing large strings in a TVF, so any filter or join to it is slow. This is why I need the FULL OUTER JOIN, because I need grib.[TimeStep] values even when there are no brain.[TimeStep] values, and having the query the other way around takes forever to run. A COALESCE works fine but then I get brain.[TimeStep] values out of the range of grib.[TimeStep] and this is also not desired, as the `TOP 720 ... ORDER BY gfm.[UTCDate] DESC` part of the GRIBS query is designed to restrict values to the last 30 days....

So my problem is that adding `WHERE grib.[TimeStep] IS NOT NULL` or `HAVING grib.[TimeStep] IS NOT NULL` makes the split-second query above take several minutes.

But I *would like* to modify the query to exclude cases where grib.[TimeStep] is null -- obviously without adding any time to the query -- I can always filter the result after running the query and only add a few microseconds, but this is not ideal. Any ideas?

Comment: `OR` performance issues can often be solved using `UNION ALL`.

Comment: For performance issues, you need to add full table and index definitions, and share query plans via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan Please explain the exact join logic you would ideally like (performance not withstanding, as I'm not clear. What about dumping `GRIBS` into a temp table and joining on that?

Comment: @Charlieface the temp table thing will probably work. If I knew what table and index definitions were and how to add them, I'd probably be skilled enough to solve this on my own. On a deadline so will solve this javascript-side and test the temp table idea if nobody comes up with a cleaner solution.

Comment: It's just a script with `CREATE TABLE...CREATE INDEX...` definitions. In SSMS you can right click the table and Generate Scripts. You can also get the query plan from SSMS. Please do [edit] and elaborate on the desired join logic. By the way, if you add the TVF also, it's possible that could also be optimized.

Comment: Nothing unclean about a temp table solution lol

Comment: @DaleK you're probably right. Only thing is this is one of several views. The other views all work fine and are fast - just this one is a pain due to the fact it is aggregated to get that average rainfall. To implement temp table I'd have to have this be the odd script out - SP rather than view. So not ideal. I suppose I could turn them all into SPs for consistency.

Comment: @Charlieface I'd just tried to edit like you asked. It threw a generic error and refused to publish and I don't know why. So no edit I guess.

Comment: Without the info I asked for, cannot advise, sorry. But you cannot have a temp table in a view obviously

Comment: @AndrewBenjamin did you try `UNION ALL` instead of `OR`? That works in a view...

Comment: @DaleK -- I reviewed UNION ALL, and my little chipmunk brain couldn't figure out how to implement it. If you add an answer I'll give it a shot and if it works I'll accept it.

Comment: Ignore that comment, I realise you're not actually trying to `OR` anything, you're telling us the 2 methods you tried. I assume you put `where ... is not null` inside the CTE? And have you tried the temp table approach below?

Answer (score 1):

Changing you solution from a CTE to a temp table as suggested by Charlieface in a comment could look like this.

```
SELECT TOP 720 
    gfm.[ID],
    gfm.[FileName],
    gfm.[UTCDate] AS [TimeStep]
INTO #GRIBS
FROM [hrdps].[GRIBFileMetrics]() gfm
WHERE gfm.[Field] = 'WEARN_SFC_0'
ORDER BY gfm.[UTCDate] DESC;

SELECT
    b.[POIID],
    grib.[TimeStep],
    AVG(ISNULL(brain.[Amount], 0.0)) AS [Rainfall],
    grib.[FileName] 
FROM [storm].[BasinRain] brain
    LEFT JOIN [storm].[BasinGCSMap] bmap ON brain.[BasinGCSMapID] = bmap.[ID]
    LEFT JOIN [storm].[Basin] b ON b.[ID] = bmap.[BasinID]
    LEFT JOIN [storm].[POI] poi ON poi.[ID] = b.[POIID]
    FULL OUTER JOIN #GRIBS grib ON brain.[TimeStep] = grib.[TimeStep]
GROUP BY b.[POIID], grib.[TimeStep], grib.[FileName];

DROP TABLE #GRIBS;
```

Put it in a stored procedure or use the entire thing ad-hoc.

Comment: I would index the temp table also, clustered key on `TimeStep, ID` would make the most sense